# iOS app not updating properly through OTA Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ios, ipad, installation, updates, ota

I have an iPad application that is distributed to a client via OTA Enterprise Distribution.  The app is distributed and installed with no problem on the client's iPads.  The problem occurs when they attempt to install a newer version of the app.

Any new resources that were added to the app bundle in the new version cannot be accessed in the latest version; the client must delete the old app first and re-install with the new version in order to see the new resources in the app bundle.

The .plist file in each of the builds specify a different number for the bundle-version so the same app bundle shouldn't be used in the newer build.

I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  Do you have any suggestions for how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with the app bundle.  Certain resources were being saved to the Documents folder (because newer versions were downloaded through the app) and the file path was being saved to the User Defaults.  When the app was updated with a new version the file path becomes invalid because the newly updated app has a different uid in the path, therefore the resources stored in the Documents folder were not found.

I modified the code to always grab the file path from NSDocumentsDirectory instead of storing and grabbing it from User Defaults; I'm not sure why it was originally implemented to store the file path.

Comment: So the updated app has a new guid in the root folder?

Comment: Hi Herman, it's been a while since I worked on this project, but I believe that was the case.  The new version of the app had a different id, so any old paths that referenced that id wouldn't find the old resources.

Comment: yep, definately the issue. Thanks, solved a long-standing issue for me.